# How to iterate over an array with rayon?

Tags: rust, rayon

I am new to rust, I am trying to get responses from an array of URLs using rayon

```
use rayon::prelude::*;
use reqwest::*;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let urls = vec!["https://example.com"];
    urls.par_iter().for_each(|url: &&str| ->  Result<()> {
        println!("Hello... {:?}", url);
        let resp = reqwest::blocking::get(url)?.text()?;
        println!("{:#?}", resp);
        Ok(())
    });
    Ok(())
}
```

but I am getting this error

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@src\main.rs:252:30: 257:6] as FnOnce<(&&str,)>>::Output == ()`
   --> src\main.rs:252:21
    |
252 |     urls.par_iter().for_each(|url| ->  Result<()> {
    |                     ^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found `()`
    |
    = note:   expected enum `std::result::Result<(), reqwest::Error>`
            found unit type `()`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&&str: IntoUrl` is not satisfied
   --> src\main.rs:254:20
    |
254 |         let resp = reqwest::blocking::get(url)?.text()?;
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `IntoUrl` is not implemented for `&&str`
    | 
   ::: mod.rs:106:15
    |
106 | pub fn get<T: crate::IntoUrl>(url: T) -> crate::Result<Response> {
    |               -------------- required by this bound in `reqwest::blocking::get`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <&'a str as IntoUrl>
```

Comment: If a request fails, do you want to continue with other requests or stop everything?

Comment: I want to continue other request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second error is the easier: `IntoUrl` is not implemented for `&&str`, but it is for `&str`. So all you need is to dereference the pointer:

```rust
urls.par_iter().for_each(|url: &&str| -> Result<()> {
    let url = *url;
```

Or

```rust
urls.par_iter().for_each(|&url: &&str| -> Result<()> {
```

The first is trickier. The problem is that `for_each()` expects a closure that returns `()`, and giving it a closure that returns `Result` does not work.

Because you want to continue with other requests if a request fails, you cannot use rayon's [`try_for_each()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.try_for_each) since it will stop all pending requests on failure. Instead, you want to just ignore the failure, perhaps log it. Using `unwrap()` is a bad idea: not just it will stop other requests, it will also abort your program! **Never** use `unwrap()`, unless you're 100% sure the code will never fail (it's also good to comment why if it isn't obvious). You can give up on the `?` operator and just be explicit:

```rust
urls.par_iter().for_each(|&url| {
    println!("Hello... {:?}", url);
    if let Ok(resp) = reqwest::blocking::get(url) {
        if let Ok(resp) = resp.text() {
            println!("{:#?}", resp);
        }
    }
});
```

But while you can improve this code a bit, it is still ugly. [`try` blocks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html) will improve the situation; until they land on stable, there is a common idiom for a block with multiple potential failure points:

```rust
urls.par_iter().for_each(|&url| {
    _ = (|| -> Result<()> {
        println!("Hello... {:?}", url);
        let resp = reqwest::blocking::get(url)?.text()?;
        println!("{:#?}", resp);
        Ok(())
    })();
});
```

This uses closure's ability to use the `?` operator to simplify the code.

Note however that `rayon` is not intended for IO-bound tasks: use async framework like `tokio`.

Answer (score 1):

`for_each` take closure/lambda whose return type is `unit` not `Result`
`?` operator cannot be used inside function/closure/lambda which return `unit -> ()`
`*` is being used to dereference and accessing the underlying string

**src/main.rs**

```rs
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let urls = vec!["https://example.com"];
    urls.par_iter().for_each(|url: &&str| {
        println!("Hello... {:?}", *url);
        let resp = reqwest::blocking::get(*url).unwrap().text();
        println!("{:#?}", resp);
    });
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "s71275260"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# see more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rayon = "1.5.1"
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["blocking"] }
```

Comment: If I uncomment the code it is not working, I still get this error 

`let resp = reqwest::blocking::get(url)?.text()?;
    | |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `()``

Comment: @Nane I have updated the answer with working solution please check